# Excel VBA Chart Auto Shape Top Left Position

Tags: vba, excel, charts, position

I have a chart in Excel. I've added a shape to the chart with:

```
excelChart.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, excelChart.ChartArea.width, 15)
```

[image: Chart with shape]

I selected the green box and ran the below macro:

```
Sub Macro6()

    Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0
    Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 0

End Sub
```

I was expecting the green box to be positioned flush in the top left of the orange chart area, but as you can see there seems to be some kind of margin before the top/left zero coordinate starts..

How can I programmatically position the green box flush in the corner?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `IncrementLeft` and `IncrementTop`.

```
Sub AddBox()
    Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart

    With cht.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, cht.ChartArea.Width, 15)
        .Name = "MyShape"
        .IncrementLeft -5  //Experiment with number to get desired effect
        .IncrementTop -5
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.  Was hoping there might be some property I could read that could give me the exact value for this margin/padding rather than hardcoding 5..

Comment: I spent a good 45 mins looking at MSDN docs on the chart object model but could not see any obvious property. Agree my solution feels a bit of a hack. Perhaps one of the VBA big hitters can illuminate this dark corner!